# Connecting to confluence via C# .Net platform and creating a new page

Tags: c#, confluence-rest-api

Is there any nuget package to login conlfuence? Or perhaps, is there a book I can read on?

I need to create a new page in confluence via code. I will need to have the page title I think, maybe some text for description. I'm sure I will need to create some connection and authentication... Where do I start? Any nuget package(s) to install?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are OFF-TOPIC for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Any books you might have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dappo.Confluence Nuget Package. However, The project community/collaborators are very limited on GitHub.

I suggest you to use regular HttpClient with [Naive Rest Api of the Confluence](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-server-rest-api/).

[Basic example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) for using HttpClient

Another Example

```
using(var client = newHttpClient())  
{  
    client.BaseAddress = newUri("http://localhost:55587/");  
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();  
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(newMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  
    //GET Method  
    HttpResponseMessage response = awaitclient.GetAsync("api/Department/1");  
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
    {  
        result = awaitresponse.Content.ReadAsAsync < Department > ();  
        ....
    }  
    else  //error 
    {  

    } 
}
```